# Gabor filter - parameters values and feature extraction in openCv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, wavelet, iris-recognition

I want to extract features in my image - cropped iris. But I have problems with parameters. I also don't know how exacly it works. I've already red a lot of topics about this issue in the web, but I can't answer my questions.

Input image:

[image: Cropped iris in cartesian]

I use OpenCV library, and I writte this code:

```
double kSize = 11.0;
double sigma = 2, theta = Math.PI/4, lambda = 4.0, gamma = 0.6;
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getGaborKernel(new Size(kSize, kSize), sigma, theta, lambda, gamma);
Mat dest = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());
Imgproc.filter2D(src, dest, CvType.CV_64F, kernel);
```

And I get the following image:

[image: Output]

If my parameters are right? I want to get some more wavelets and display it in my application. How should I changing params to get good results? 
I also want to extract and save a Gabor features. Could someone place some piece of code as an answer for this question?

I will be verry glad if someone want to help me. I get stuck with this, and I try to code this 3 day..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948110/gabor-kernel-parameters-in-opencv